# What means "CDF of one group does not cross the CDF of the other" from the dunn.test description?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, dunn-test

From the `dunn.test` manual: *"CDF of one group does not cross the CDF of the other"*. What this means? I am not a statistician, but I want to understand. What I found using a Google search not helped me very much :(.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, but I do not see any duplication, maybe only a partial one. We asked two different things! Anyway, I don't see there an answer to my question.

Comment: I checked again.  Glen_b's answer points out that "The step-functions can coincide, but the x-sample ecdf will never be above/left of the y-sample ecdf." That is a clear, straightforward (and graphically illustrated) response that directly answers your question.

Comment: OK! I had to write in bold: I'm not a statistician! :-) For me that was not clear, not understandable, but after the @tim answer now is clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDF's are [Cumulative Distribution Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), i.e. they tell you about the probability that some value $X$ is less or equal then $x$, $F(x) = P(X \leq x)$.

Below you can see the example of crossing and non crossing CDF's:

```
set.seed(123)

n <- 1e3
x <- sort(rnorm(n, 0, 1))
y <- sort(rnorm(n, 1, 1))
z <- sort(rnorm(n, .5, 2))

plot(x, (1:n)/n, type="l", xlim=c(-4, 4), ylab="F(x)")
lines(y, (1:n)/n, col="red")
lines(z, (1:n)/n, col="green")
```

[image]

On the y-axis there are cumulative probabilities and on the x-axis values of the variables. Lines black (`x`) and red (`y`) do not cross, while green (`z`) crosses both black and white. What this plot tells you is that values of `x` and `y` go in parallel, because the only difference between them is that their mean value is different. Distribution of `z` is different because it has different standard deviation, so its CDF also differs.

Now, if you read again the manual of `dunn.test` function in R (bold font by myself):

> The interpretation of stochastic dominance requires an assumption that
>   the CDF of one group does not cross the CDF of the other. (...) The
>   null hypothesis for each pairwise comparison is that the probability
>   of observing a randomly selected value from the first group that is
>   larger than a randomly selected value from the second group equals one
>   half; this null hypothesis corresponds to that of the
>   Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney rank-sum test. Like the rank-sum test, if the
>   data can be assumed to be continuous, and the **distributions are
>   assumed identical except for a difference in location**, Dunn’s test may
>   be understood as a test for median difference

...you can see the assumption of [Dunn test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/dunn-test/info) is that the distributions are the same and differ just by location (i.e. mean). This is exactly what is illustrated on the plot I pasted, where `x` and `y` have different mean but `z` has also different standard deviation and so its distribution has different shape.

Comment: One minor quibble: the assumption in the discussion of stochastic dominance in relation to Dunn's test is about population distributions, while your illustration is about sample (i.e. empirical) CDFs.

Comment: OK, but I would say that population distribution makes not a very clear example ;)

Comment: @Tim Thank you! You helped me to understand this! Cheers!

Comment: Tim -- The example is fine, as is the reference to it for motivation/clarification when discussing the paragraph from the manual; I just thought it important to point out the distinction between the sample and the population -- thinking hypotheses are statements about samples is a common confusion many people carry in respect of hypothesis tests. I believe it pays to emphasize that they are statements about populations when there's any potential for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

CDF is a monotonously increasing curve with y-values going from 0 to 1 and x values going through the entire domain. If you draw two curves on the same graph, they may or may not cross each other. They'll definite connect at y=0 and 1.